# PYTHON: Print X items of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, counter

I have this code:

```
U = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

def bla(anzahl):
    zaehlwerk = 0
    while zaehlwerk < anzahl:
        for x in U:
            zaehlwerk = zaehlwerk +1
            print x
```

my query:

```
bla(3)
```

I hoped that now I would get the first 3 list items, but instead I get the whole list.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

I tried to debug because I thought that maybe the counter wouldn't work, but it does. But then where is my error?

Comment: for x in U runs for all x in U and the while loop is only checked the first time. Get a debugger/IDE and step through the code one line at a time.

Comment: thats what i did (like stated above), because i thought the counter was the error. how can i get the while loop checked again?

Comment: In situations like this, just look at each line of code sequentially, take it literally and you'll figure it out.... i.e. "while i<j:     for each element in the list do... (Oh! duh!, i'm telling the program to go through each element of the list each time!)"    p.s.   all you really need is :         print U[:3] <- 'cause python's awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x in U:
```

is the innermost loop.  That is making sure you iterate over everything.

As is you can modify your code to look like

```
def bla(anzahl):
    zaehlwerk = 0
    while zaehlwerk < anzahl:
        x = U[zaehlwerk]
        zaehlwerk = zaehlwerk +1
        print x
```

And that will work for what you want.  But more concise would be to to use something like

```
for index in range(len(anzahl)):
    print U[index]
```

Answer (score 6):

use slicing :

```
>>> U = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> U[:3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

`U[stat-index:end-index]`, you will get element from start-index to one less end-index, as in above example

```
>>>U[2:6]
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

what you need to do is this using slicing:

```
def print_list(n):
    print "\n".join(map(str,U[:n]))
print_list(3)
```

output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: The starting `0` is not necessary here.

Comment: slicing wouldnt help me, because that just gives me a new list.

Comment: @bngschmnd when u got the list you can print it

Comment: @bngschmnd chek the code how it print, edited as per your requirement